# Changing Data Type Prevented in Oracle SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to change the data type of different keys in my database, via the Oracle SQL Developer User interface.
However, when I try to change it I get the error: "Column USERS.U_ID cannot be changed, it is referenced or used by a foreign key"
Now even if I remove all foreign key constraints I still get this error.
Any ideas on how to avoid this?

Comment: did you remove FK constraints to that table (not from that table) ?

Comment: I disabled, not removed

Comment: I would try removing those linking to that specific field, from other tables.